# Django reverse lookup in API

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I would like to know how I have get a list of all related animals in my TastyPie api/houses call:

For example:

House Model:

```
class House(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Each house can have one or more of the following:

```
class Dog(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      house = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True)

class Cat(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      house = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True)

class Hamster(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      house = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True)

class Fish(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
      house = models.ForeignKey(House, null=True)
```

**This returns:**

```
[
{
id: 1,
description: "Test Offer22",
user: {
date_joined: "2014-01-02T18:39:40",
email: "me@something.org",
id: 1,
is_active: true,
last_login: "2014-01-05T15:44:30"
}
},
```

I would like in this JSON to also see a list of all animals that are related to the house i.e. cat, dog. Can this be done in Tastypie? I have read about [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) is this what I'm after here? I don't really understand how you get a relationship from the `'wrong'` side, if you know that I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`full=True` argument](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=full#full) for your [related fields](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=full#relationship-fields). For example:

```
class HouseResource(ModelResource):
    dogs = fields.ToManyField('DogResource', 'dog_set', full=True)
```